# How to show $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ is homeomorphic to $S_1 \times S_1$ and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is homeomorphic to $S_1$ thus the product is homeomorphic to $S_1 \times S_1$. But I wonder if there's a way to show the quotient spaces are homeomorphic without having to refer to $S_1$.

Comment: @C.Dubussy thanks for helping with the formatting!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider two spaces $A,B$ with equivalence relations $R,S$. Then $R\times S$ is an equivalence relation, and there is a natural map $p:(A\times B)/(R\times S)\to A/R\times B/S$. This is always a continuous bijection, but might not be an homeomorphism. In your case since the spaces are compact Hausdorff, it is. One can weaken the hypothesis, however. I wouldn't know to what extent.

Comment: Ok, I think I know how to go on from here. Thanks!

Comment: @Ahctun If this answer helped you then you should consider accepting it by clicking on the green arrow next to it. That way it won't be categorized as an unanswered question by this site.